# Flatten dynamic list of list in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following json which I'm decoding in dart:

```
[{"page":1, "items": [1, 2]}, {"page":2, "items": [3, 4]}]
```

I'd like to flatten it into a single list of items: `[1, 2, 3, 4]`. The first, naive, way I tried was this:

```
final x = items.expand((p) => p['items']);
```

But it gives me this error:

```
Uncaught exception:
TypeError: Closure 'main_closure': type '(dynamic) => dynamic' is not a subtype of type '(dynamic) => Iterable<dynamic>'
```

So I assume the problem is that `p['items']` is not being recognized as an Iterable, then I tried other ways but none works:

```
final x = items.expand((p) => p['items'] as List<int>);
// CastError: Instance of 'JSArray': type 'JSArray' is not a subtype of type 'List<int>'

final x = items.expand((p) => p['items'].map((i) => i as int);
// TypeError: Closure 'main_closure': type '(dynamic) => dynamic' is not a subtype of type '(dynamic) => Iterable<dynamic>'
```

Here's the code, also in a [dartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/9f654528d2f8d05abc14a7bd9282bda3) for running online:

```
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  const jsonString = '[{"page":1, "items": [1, 2]}, {"page":2, "items": [3, 4]}]';
  final items = json.decode(jsonString);
  //final x = items.expand((p) => p['items']);
  //final x = items.expand((p) => p['items'].map((i) => i as int);
  print(x);

  // When the list is not dynamic, it works
  const foo = [{"page":1, "items": [11, 22]}, {"page":2, "items": [33, 44]}];
  final y = foo.expand((p) => p['items']);
  print(y); // => [1, 2, 3, 4];

  // Example from dart's website
  const pairs = [[1, 2], [3, 4]];
  final flattened = pairs.expand((pair) => pair).toList();
  print(flattened); // => [1, 2, 3, 4];
}
```

How can I use do this when the list is dynamic? The json seemed simple enough to do it with `json.decode` rather than setting up something like built_value to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just cast the decoded object to `List`

```
const jsonString = '[{"page":1, "items": [1, 2]}, {"page":2, "items": [3, 4]}]';
final items = json.decode(jsonString) as List;
final x = items.expand((p) => p['items']);
print(x);
```

Or using a fixed `List` type:

```
final List items = json.decode(jsonString);
```